# Replace all + into spaces in field Logstash

Tags: logstash

I want to turn my field:

```
"device_model": "archos+Bush+7.0+MyTablet"
```

into

```
"device_model": "archos Bush 7.0 MyTablet"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub

```
filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      # replace all plusses with spaces
      "device_model", "\+", " "
    ]
  }
}
```